# EF is not removing many to many relation in DB

Tags: c#, entity-framework

There are 2 entities:

User <-> Role (many to many)

User has `List<Role> Roles`

Role has `List<User> Users`

User Mapping

```
HasMany(x => x.Roles)
            .WithMany(x => x.Users)
            .Map(x =>
            {
                x.ToTable("UserRole");
                x.MapLeftKey("UserId");
                x.MapRightKey("RoleId");
            });
```

Role Mapping

```
HasMany(x => x.Users)
            .WithMany(x => x.Roles)
            .Map(x =>
            {
                x.ToTable("UserRole");
                x.MapLeftKey("RoleId");
                x.MapRightKey("UserId");
            });
```

When i try removing this relation without removing actual entities in Db, nothing actually happens, row in UserRole table still exists.

```
private void CleanUp(User user)
    {
        var role = user.Roles[0];
        user.Roles.Remove(role);
        role.Users.Remove(user);
        client.UpdateUser(user);
        client.UpdateRole(role);
    }
```

Update Methods in my service:

```
public void UpdateRole(Role entity)
    {
        _unitOfWork.RoleRepository.Update(entity);
        _unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
    }

 public void UpdateUser(User entity)
 {
 try
 {
     _unitOfWork.UserRepository.Update(entity);
     _unitOfWork.SaveChanges();
 }
     catch (Exception e)
 {
     Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
 }
```

Generic Repository Update method:

```
 public void Update(TEntity entity)
    {
        var entry = _context.Entry(entity);
        if (entry.State == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            Set.Attach(entity);
            entry = _context.Entry(entity);
        }
        entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
```

UpdateRole/UpdateUser methods don't throw any exceptions, when `CleanUp()` is executed, row in UserRole table still exists. If i retrieve entities again from dbContext, Users and Roles list's are actually empty, it's just DB not updating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how your uow is implemented, but the problem is that when you remove the relationship:

```
user.Roles.Remove(role);
role.Users.Remove(user);
```

these operationa are not being tracked by a `DbContext`. If you do exactly what you're doing, but inside a `DbContext` scope, it will work perfectly.